# Translating wrapper-/proxy- pattern to redux

Tags: design-patterns, proxy, redux, wrapper

I am currently investigating reduxjs as a viable framework for an upcoming project.
There, we migrate from an old solution, which makes heavy use of the proxy/wrapper pattern.

i.e.:

- there are models which are kept dumb (pojo) intentionally. They only carry data. Let's assume these are tasks
- Now these tasks are wrapped dynamically with objects that add cross-cutting features like validation and change tracking to them.

Now: Whenever the property is changed, in effect, 3 changes to the application state may happen. 
E.g.:

1. the "title" property of the task is changed
2. as this change is done throught the wrapper/proxy, it detects the change and

   2. a) updates the "haschagnes" field to "true"
   3. b) and (potentially) adds a validation error to the "validationErrors" list

As far as I understand, in Redux, every action should only be handled once and lead to 1 atomic state change.
However, in this case, it would be up to three changes.

So my question is:
Is it possible to translate this wrapper/proxy- pattern based approach to a redux style one?
And if so, how? (Middleware, WrapperReducer, ...?)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand, in Redux, every action should only be handled once and lead to 1 atomic state change. However, in this case, it would be up to three changes.

That's a misconception.  In Redux, a single dispatched action can be handled by multiple reducers.  These changes are then applied at the same time (even though it is 1 atomic state change, multiple properties have been changed).

As far as I can tell, your use case should be implementable with Redux.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this!